# The type or namespace name `PostProcessing' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine.Rendering'

Tags: unity-game-engine

Do someone know how to fix this? I got this error after importing Cinemachine from the Unity Asset Store. I'm using Unity 2018.1.0f2 and have no problems with 2017.3.1f1

Error

The type or namespace name `PostProcessing` does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine.Rendering`

Comment: [May be a known issue](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/issues/561)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Unity 2018.2 --

Go to Window>Package Manager
Click on the All tab
Find Postprossessing and import
Find Cinemachine and import

Comment: I couldn't find Cinemachine in the Packages list, I'm using Unity Version 2018.2.0f2 Personal in Mac

Answer (score 4):

here's something that should work - it worked for me!
go to window > package manager. search for postprocessing and click install. wait for it to download. close package manager. DONE!

Answer (score 4):

The Way I found to Fix This Error is This:
 1. go to Window -> package manager
 2. select post-processing
 3. click on version and select old version
 4. click Up to date